# "X applies to Y as well as Z." — Can it mean both "X applies to Y as well as X applies to Z" and "X applies to Y as well as Z applies to Y"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, ellipsis, as, coordination, attachment-ambiguity

my own sentence:
**(1)** *X applies to Y as well as Z*.

I think (1) is ambiguous and can mean two things:
**(2)** *X applies to Y as well as **X applies to** Z*. — If "*X applies to*" was omitted in (1).
**(3)** *X applies to Y as well as Z **applies to Y***. — If "*applies to Y*" was omitted in (1).

Am I right about this?
If not, then why not?

Comment: In any real situation, X,Y, and Z would be actual phrases and I doubt there would be any ambiguity.  Can you give an example without the metasyntactic variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be ambiguous. Usually it won't be too confusing in context, but sometimes we need to elide fewer words so it's clear what's being coordinated.

> X applies to Y as well as **to** Z. (same as 2)

> X applies to Y **and so does** Z. (same as 3)

> X applies to Y as Z **does**. (same as 3)

Note "as well as," as an idiom, isn't really able to coordinate two independent clauses the way you've done in your expansions. I bring this up mainly to explain why my examples are a little different from (3). To keep it exactly the same, we *could* do this:

> X applies to Y as well as Z **does**.

But then instead of "as well" meaning "also," we'd be saying "as well" meaning "in a way just as good" (as your examples inadvertently do). In a similar sentence not containing this particular idiom—or where the non-idiomatic meaning was the intended one—this would be a valid and straightforward rephrasing.

Here's one more example to illustrate how common this kind of thing is in English:

> Alice likes Bob more than Carol.

may mean either of

> (?) Alice likes Bob more than Carol **does**.

> (?) Alice likes Bob more than **she likes** Carol.

Comment: I understood (1) can mean "_X applies to Y as well as **to** Z_." But I didn't understand what else (1) can mean: "_X applies to Y **and so does** Z_" or "_X applies to Y **in the way as** Z **does**_". Could you clarify this please?

Comment: @Loviii (1) can mean "X applies to Y and so does Z". "*X applies to Y in the way as Z does" hasn't been referenced anywhere and isn't grammatical, so I'm not sure what you're asking about it.

Comment: In the comments to the other answer, I was told that "_She has invited Jill as well as Kate_" can't mean "_She has invited Jill **and so has** Kate_". But based on your answer, I take it you think it can, right?

Comment: @Loviii That one is less likely, but possible. I don't agree with the other answer or its finality on the matter—we can debate whether there's a context that would make that particular sentence natural (admittedly, it's a stretch), but it's incontestable that confusion _is_ possible with similar sentences.